# Check Nulls in Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

We have the following code to check if the given username and password exists in database:

```
    public User GetUserByUserNameAndPassword(string userName, string userPassword)
    {
        using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
        {
            return Mapper.Map(context.UserEntities.Single(u => u.UserName == userName && u.UserPassword == userPassword));
        }
    }
```

If we have the username and password in database this works fine but throws an error if username or password is wrong and no records found.

This might be simple but as I am new to lambda could not get get it right.

How can I change the lambda query so we can handle nulls?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx), which will return only one record or null if none exists.

```
return Mapper.Map(context.UserEntities.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName && u.UserPassword == userPassword));
```

Later you can check:

```
User returnedObject = GetUserByUserNameAndPassword(username,password)

if(returnedObject == null)
{
//User doesn't exist
}
```

*Remember Single/SingleOrDefault will throw an exception if multiple records exist against the criteria.*

Answer (score 2):

You should change from `Single` to [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx), it returns null when no data match

```
context.UserEntities.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName && 
                                          u.UserPassword == userPassword)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.Any()` will return true if a matching record is found or false if no record is found.

So a slight modifcation to you existing code will work.

```
      public User GetUserByUserNameAndPassword(string userName, string userPassword)
        {
            using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
            {
             if (context.UserEntities.Any(u => u.UserName == userName && u.UserPassword == userPassword))
             {
                return Mapper.Map(context.UserEntities.Single(u => u.UserName == userName && u.UserPassword == userPassword));
             }
             else
             {
              //Deal with no user here through chosen method
             }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is also the possibility of some other thread or application executing something that will invalidate the result from `Any` in such a way that the `Single` operation will fail anyway. It's better to try and fail, and avoid a TOCTOU race condition.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefualt and check for null like as below

```
var user =context.UserEntities.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName 
                                           && 
                                           u.UserPassword == userPassword);

if(user!=null)
{
 //do code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) and check for `Null` prior to calling Map

```
public User GetUserByUserNameAndPassword(string userName, string userPassword) 
{ 
    using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext()) 
    { 
        var user = context.UserEntities.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName && u.UserPassword == userPassword);
        return user !=null ? Mapper.Map(user) : null; 
    } 
}
```